# Concatenate 2 JSON arrays in PHP when elements loading dynamically from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I'm working with a Laravel API and I have the following requirement. I'm querying the database and taking some orders. I'm checking a contract_id and I'm using 2 SQL queries to get orders with contract ID and also orders without a contract ID.

```
public function totalOrdersTest(Request $request)
{

    $from = new DateTime($request->query->get('from'));
    $to = new DateTime($request->query->get('to'));
    $manufacturer_id = $request->query->get('manu');
    $article_template_id = $request->query->get('article_template_id');

    if ($article_template_id == '' || $article_template_id == null) {
        $results_not_null = Order::selectRaw('count(*) not_null_order_count, DATE_FORMAT(orders.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as order_date')
            ->filterManufacturer($manufacturer_id)
            ->join('order_items', 'order_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->whereNotNull('order_items.tariff_id')
            ->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [$from, $to])
            ->groupBy('order_date')
            ->orderBy('order_date')
            ->get();

        $results_null = Order::selectRaw('count(*) null_order_count, DATE_FORMAT(orders.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as order_date')
            ->filterManufacturer($manufacturer_id)
            ->join('order_items', 'order_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->whereNull('order_items.tariff_id')
            ->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [$from, $to])
            ->groupBy('order_date')
            ->orderBy('order_date')
            ->get();
    } else {
        $result = Order::selectRaw('count(*) order_count, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as order_date')
            ->filterArticleTemplate($article_template_id)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
            ->groupBy('order_date')
            ->orderBy('order_date')
            ->get();
    }

    // Need to concatenate ´$results_not_null´ & ´$results_null´ and take a one JSON array. 
}
```

From this code, I have this JSON array with 2 objects.

```
{"results_not_null":[{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-09"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-06-19"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-29"},{"not_null_order_count":5,"order_date":"2020-07-06"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-07-07"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-07-08"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-07-15"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-07-17"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-07-22"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-07-31"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-08-01"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-08-03"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-08-15"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-08-27"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-15"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-17"},{"not_null_order_count":4,"order_date":"2020-09-18"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-09-19"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-20"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-21"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-09-22"},{"not_null_order_count":5,"order_date":"2020-09-23"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-24"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-09-25"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-26"},{"not_null_order_count":5,"order_date":"2020-09-27"},{"not_null_order_count":5,"order_date":"2020-09-28"},{"not_null_order_count":5,"order_date":"2020-09-29"},{"not_null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-09-30"},{"not_null_order_count":4,"order_date":"2020-10-01"},{"not_null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-10-02"},{"not_null_order_count":4,"order_date":"2020-10-04"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-10-05"},{"not_null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-10-06"},{"not_null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-10-07"},{"not_null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-10-08"}],"results_null":[{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-09"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-15"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-18"},{"null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-06-19"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-23"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-25"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-06-29"},{"null_order_count":21,"order_date":"2020-07-06"},{"null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-07-07"},{"null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-07-08"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-07-15"},{"null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-07-17"},{"null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-07-19"},{"null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-07-22"},{"null_order_count":3,"order_date":"2020-07-24"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-07-31"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-08-01"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-08-03"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-08-04"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-08-15"},{"null_order_count":5,"order_date":"2020-08-27"},{"null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-09-02"},{"null_order_count":2,"order_date":"2020-09-13"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-15"},{"null_order_count":1,"order_date":"2020-09-17"},{"null_order_count":4,"order_date":"2020-10-01"}]}
```

But I need to concatenate these 2 JSON arrays. The most important task it in both arrays, there are same date and then I need to use them in one element. For example,

```
[
{
"order_date":"2020-12-12",
"not_null_order_count": 2,
"null_order_count":3
},
{
"order_date":"2020-12-13",
"not_null_order_count": 12,
"null_order_count":5
},
{
"order_date":"2020-12-14",
"null_order_count":9
}
]
```

This is the output I need to have. Sometimes one date has only null_order_count or not_null_order_count.

Is there any method we can do this using one MySQL query? Or how to combine these 2 arrays and make one JSON array? Please advice.

Comment: can you post the final sql query ? You can do this with 1 query by using SUM(CASE WHEN .. but I'm pretty sure you have to write it with native sql

Comment: @AngelDeykov Hey, did you mean the native SQL query generated by the Laravel ORM?

Comment: yes, can you post it as well

Comment: @AngelDeykov Please check the code here: https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/0a4d0e89e0f13dd818e0d3aa8437158b

Answer (score 0):

try to merge both jsons:

```
   \json_encode(array_merge(\json_decode($json1, true), \json_decode($json2, true)))
```

Comment: it is not working. I need to combine these 2 arrays and then have following response.  [
{
"order_date":"2020-12-12",
"not_null_order_count": 2,
"null_order_count":3
},
{
"order_date":"2020-12-13",
"not_null_order_count": 12,
"null_order_count":5
},
{
"order_date":"2020-12-14",
"null_order_count":9
}
]